# DotNetOpenAuth & MvcOpenID - Works locally but not on production server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth

I'm implementing OpenID with an MVC app and pretty much uses the MvcOpenID on CodePlex (http://mvcopenid.codeplex.com/), which also implements DotNetOpenAuth. My site work well locally, but somehow it doesn't work when deployed to my server. When tracing it with Firebug, it says "Failed to load http://www.kennysax.com/User/Login/ ...", but again, it worked locally, just localhost vs. my domain name.

If you want to check out, you can visit my site (http://www.kennysax.com - just a personal blog) and login with an supported OpenID provider...

Thanks.

Comment: WhenI navigate to http://www.kennysax.com/User/Login/ it seems to work fine. No js errors reported in FireBug.

Comment: Darin, were you able to login? I know there aren't any error with js, code, etc.. because it works locally! Thanks.

Comment: I didn't see any error, but there was no visual cue that I was logged in either -- it just looked like the original login page.

Comment: Yah, then it's not working :) That's what I'm also getting, I should be redirected to a registration page and the "Login" menu button should display user information instead. :( Not sure what is going on as I can't debug the code on the server, and my local code is working correctly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It confused the heck out of me, luckily, I was able to remote to my production machine, run the stock MVCOpenId project, step through the debug and see the error. The error was `This message has already been processed. This could indicate a replay attack in progress`, and it seems to be related to a setting on DotNetOpenAuth (I wish I could some how see that message without having to debug the code!). A setting in the web.config solved it, change the maxAuthenticationTime to `0:10`:

`<openid maxAuthenticationTime="0:10" ... ...`

Thanks all for looking.